# Create many samples from one dataframe with for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have this df
create columns l and l1:

```
l1=[]
for i in range(1005,1105):
    l1.append(i)

l=[]
for i in range(1005,1105):
    l.append(i)

d = {'col1': l1, 'col2': l}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Now I would like create 10 samples with 10 rows each:

like sample_1, sample_2 up to sample_10.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTKhv.png)
How I make this?

My loop for doesn't work

```
for j in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]: 
    sample_[j] = df.sample(n=10, random_state=j)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `sample_` is not a data container (list or dictionary, for instance). Try the following:

```py
sample_ = {}
for j in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]: 
    sample_[j] = df.sample(n=10, random_state=j)
```

Then, access your samples as, e.g.:

```py
>>> sample_[1]

    col1  col2
80  1085  1085
84  1089  1089
33  1038  1038
81  1086  1086
93  1098  1098
17  1022  1022
36  1041  1041
82  1087  1087
69  1074  1074
65  1070  1070
```

Comment: is it possible without dict or lists?

Comment: You mean using variables directly ('sample_1', 'sample_2', etc)? I _guess_ you can, by doing some nasty, adhoc definitions to your _locals_ ... but why?! You don't want to do that (although trying it would be a nice _exercise_). Using a data container (dictionary, for instance) gives you a great control over your data/code.